# How to loop over custom plugin data on the template in django cms 3.5.3

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am trying to implement a website that uses RSS Feeds.
My use case is to be able to display one RSS feed at a time, then loop over to the next maybe after 5 seconds. These RSS feeds need to be displayed on the same placeholder. 
I am new to django cms in case you need more info please let me know.

I have googled a lot but all I can see is how to add plugins from the frontend and they will all automatically show inside the placeholder.
Or modify the render method of the custom plugin class to display what you want.
But I want to display everything but one at a time in a continuous manner

```
@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class ExternalArticlePlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = ExternalArticle
    name = _("External article")
    render_template = "external_article.html"
    cache = False

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(ExternalArticlePlugin, self).render(
            context, instance, placeholder
        )
        return context
```

I expect to display one RSS feed at a time inside my placeholder.
Those feeds are links to the actual webpage with more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way would be to write a function `random_rss_feed_url()` in ExternalArticle Model which renders a random rss instance.

model.py

```
class ExternalArticle(models.Model):

    def random_rss_feed_link(self):
        return ExternalArticle.objects.order_by('?')[0].link
```

then you do in plugins external_article.html:

```
{{ instance.random_rss_feed_link }}
```

**Edited**:

if you want to change automatically without page reload, then you need something like this in javascript in your template:

```
var rss_links = ['link_1', 'link_2', 'link_3']; 

setInterval(function() {

    // take random rss link
    var random_link = rss_links[Math.floor(Math.random()*rss_links.length)];

    // change the link 
    document.getElementById('rss_link_element').href = random_link;

}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I tried it out. It works but one thing still remaining. I would like it to have like a timer, whereby it display the first link for n seconds then replaces it with the next one and so forth automatically. Now I think I have to refresh the page manually to see the next random feed. Thanks

Comment: @joseluke ok, then you better render all the links and switch in frontend with javascript, I will update the answer

Comment: One small thing. How do I replace ['link_1', 'link_2', 'link_3'] with mine from the db? Do I do the conversion from the `ExternalArticle` or from `ExternalArticlePlugin`? Because currently I cannot use `instance` just like that

Comment: This is what I have in my template
```
{% for i in instance.random_rss_feed_link  %}
    <a href="{{ i.url }}">{{ i.title }}</a> <br>
{% endfor %}
```
can you help me use this instead of `['link_1', 'link_2', 'link_3']` ?

Comment: @joseluke yes, you will query all the objects of ExternalArticle Model and render them as a list via your Plugin Class

Comment: Can you send me a sample code, please? I have been trying it out for quite some time but it is still not working!